# Summing up values for clients in different rows

Tags: excel, math, formula, analysis

In Excel I'm trying to sum up the values in a column to work out the total number of within a company with multiple row

```
Company     Number   Total
   A         15       SUM A
   A         30
   A         5
   B         215      SUM B
   B         30
   C         36       SUM C
   D         24       SUM D
   D         8000
```

I need to work out how to get a total value for A, B, C etc fora couple hundred firms in the output column "total"

Comment: Need to compare trends over quarters for each company

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SUMIF function to summate the values in the number column if they match a certain company. For example:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A30,"=A",B1:B30)
```

Would sum the number(column B) value for all "A" companies. You could also link evaluation criteria to something like this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A30,"=" & C1,B1:B30)
```

If the c column held the names of each company.

Answer (score 0):

You could use formulas like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A500="A")*(B2:B500))
```

one each for each Company.....*(adjust the limits to match your data)*

Comment: Would I have to replace "A" with the company name or would it just pick from column A? I have 2000+ companies in this set so I'd rather it be automatic

Comment: You can put a list of company names into another column (say column `D`) and then reference that in the formula as follows ... `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A500=D1)*(B2:B500))`